# Regex - With Space and Special Characters

Tags: regex, special-characters, letters

I'm using the following Regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9]\s{2,20}$` for input

- Letters A - Z
- Letters a - z
- Numbers 0 - 9

The input length must be a least 2 characters and maximum 20 characters.

I also want to enable space in the input, but only space, not new line, etc.

Last thing I have problem with is that I want to enable characters such as `!@#$%^&*)(`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add characters to your regex code like this~

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 !@#$%^&*)(]{2,20}$
```

the `\s` is not only express space..

Comment: Another question if I may: How can I add to the special characters the caracters ' Apostrophe ?

Comment: @Guy Dor - try `^[a-zA-Z0-9 !@#$%^&*)(']{2,20}$`

Answer (score 1):

Try `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{2,20}$`.

And are you sure your original expression worked? The quantifier `{2,20}` is only applied to the `\s`, and not to your set inside `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second part of your question, just put those characters inside of `[]`, no escaping needed.

Answer (score 0):

All of Special Characters and char and number and with Space

[A-Za-z0-9-.& ,+!@#$%\^*();\/|<>"'?=:\t_\n[]{}~`]

Answer (score 0):

*** Regex for all types of special characters and normal characters too with space in between them.

Declare the below in some variable and perform your task:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]{2,20}$/
```

*** Regex for all types of special characters with spaces:

```
/^[ !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]{2,20}$/
```

<sub>(answer is tried and tested!!)</sub>