# Check space or special chracter using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I want to match a regular expression with in a string to match either space or special chracter '/'.

Here's my code

```
preg_match_all('/[\s]+('.$pattern.')/', $p_des, $matches_product);
```

This code is checking the spacing properlly, but I also want to include OR condition where it can check either space or '/', or digit.

I have tried a `/[[0-9]\s\/]('.$pattern.')/'` pattern, but it does not match the strings.

Thanks.

Comment: So, try `'/[\s\/]('.$pattern.')/'`

Comment: try this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889963/regex-with-space-and-special-characters

Comment: Thanks for your answer @WiktorStribiżew, its really worked for me. Suppose I have to add another Or condition for checking the digit too. Then the expression would be /[[0-9]\s\/]('.$pattern.')/'. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Well, please think of your requirements first, try something yourself, and then come up with a question. A digit can be matched with `[0-9]`, but you can't put the character class inside a character class without breaking it (unless it is a POSIX character class). So, it will look like `'/[0-9\s\/]('.$pattern.')/'`

Comment: Sorry @WiktorStribiżew, I didn't placed my requirment complely as I just found out some new needs for the functionality and thanks for your solution, its really working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `[[0-9]\s\/](string|text)` pattern is broken since a character class `[0-9]` is put inside a character class `[\s\/]`, and the first unescaped `]` closes the character class and the rest of the character class pattern is treated as a *sequence* of subpatterns (`[[0-9]\s\/]` matches `[` or digit and then a whitespace followed with `/`, e.g. `1 /` or `[ 2`).

You need to use `[0-9\s\/]` or `[\d\s\/]` instead.

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9\s\/]+('.$pattern.')/', $p_des, $matches_product);
```